# How to split a String in Beanshell in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I'm beginner in Jmeter. I need to split a string in Beanshell Postprocessor. My String contains :

```
[{name=Rose, id=2, Job=manag, AGE=45}, {name=Mary, id=3, Job=eng, AGE=67}, 
{name=Terese, id=4, Job=exe, AGE=20}, {name=George, id=5, Job=eng, AGE=50}, 
{name=Mathew, id=6, Job=cwit, AGE=30}, {name=jiss, id=7, Job=bd, AGE=49}, 
{name=Rose, id=8, Job=exe, AGE=36}]
```

How can I split each value in beanshell like:

```
- [Rose,2,manag,45]
- [Mary, 3, eng, 67] etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I doubt you should be using Beanshell at all, [since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to go for JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting

Are you sure that the string is exactly in that format? I'm asking because it's looks like to be a [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) and if this is the case you're getting response which looks like:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Rose",
    "id": 2,
    "Job": "manag",
    "AGE": 45
  },
  {
    "name": "Mary",
    "id": 3,
    "Job": "eng",
    "AGE": 67
  },
  {
    "name": "Terese",
    "id": 4,
    "Job": "exe",
    "AGE": 20
  },
  {
    "name": "George",
    "id": 5,
    "Job": "eng",
    "AGE": 50
  },
  {
    "name": "Mathew",
    "id": 6,
    "Job": "cwit",
    "AGE": 30
  },
  {
    "name": "jiss",
    "id": 7,
    "Job": "bd",
    "AGE": 49
  },
  {
    "name": "Rose",
    "id": 8,
    "Job": "exe",
    "AGE": 36
  }
]
```

You can use [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and the following Groovy code:

```
new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).each { entry ->
    log.info(entry as String)
}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: It's not json. It is the resultant row wise data from the database while using JDBC Sampler which is stored as a string.

Comment: If this is a ResultSet coming from JDBC Test Elemenents there is much easier way of working with it than parsing the string, see [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) article for details